Shopify HMAC Validation: Different Results for Same URL on Local vs AWS Server
I'm having an issue with Shopify HMAC validation where identical URLs produce different results on local versus production server.
Environment
Local: Python/Django development server (validation succeeds)
Production: AWS Server (validation fails)
API Secret: Same Shopify API secret in both environments
Example URLs
Both environments receive identical URLs:
Local (succeeds):
https://local.test.com/api/install/?hmac=c1ffa63a47d4781b34dc820bcb96344d085d6b95ef642939b67c5b3f8f411b04&host=YWRtaW4uc2hvcGlmeS5jb20vc3RvcmUvYXBwaGVhbHRoY2hlY2s&shop=apphealthcheck.myshopify.com&timestamp=1731044050 [example URL]

Production (fails):
https://server.test.com/api/install/?hmac=c1ffa63a47d4781b34dc820bcb96344d085d6b95ef642939b67c5b3f8f411b04&host=YWRtaW4uc2hvcGlmeS5jb20vc3RvcmUvYXBwaGVhbHRoY2hlY2s&shop=apphealthcheck.myshopify.com&timestamp=1731044050 [example URL]

Server Logs
[08/Nov/2024 05:32:34] "GET /api/install/?hmac=2b9feb2de99f3199f5a3f798452d88fb9769184aca436d38cd2f09b4436f207d&host=YWRtaW4uc2hvcGlmeS5jb20vc3RvcmUvYXBwaGVhbHRoY2hlY2s&shop=apphealthcheck.myshopify.com&timestamp=1731043814 HTTP/1.1" 200 5
Validating hmac...
Query string: host=YWRtaW4uc2hvcGlmeS5jb20vc3RvcmUvYXBwaGVhbHRoY2hlY2s&shop=apphealthcheck.myshopify.com&timestamp=1731043931
HMAC received: 2b9feb2de99f3199f5a3f798452d88fb9769184aca436d38cd2f09b4436f207d
HMAC calculated: d16e72b71df76ed89c9cf8952e138d8b3712e9c8bf36e7b9f1656bc5c3657699


HMAC VALIDATION CODE:
def validate_hmac(**kwargs):
    print("Validating hmac...")
    api_secret = getattr(settings, 'SHOPIFY_API_SECRET', '')
    hmac_val = kwargs.pop('hmac')
    
    # Create query string
    query_string = "&".join([f"{k}={kwargs[k]}" for k in sorted(kwargs)])
    print(f"Query string: {query_string}")
    print(f"HMAC received: {hmac_val}")
    
    # Calculate HMAC
    hmac_calc = hmac.new(api_secret.encode('utf-8'), 
                        query_string.encode('utf-8'), 
                        hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    print(f"HMAC calculated: {hmac_calc}")
    
    return hmac_calc == hmac_val



Verified API secrets are identical in both environments.
Confirmed the parameters are identical.
Added logging to track parameter values.

